# Determine when user returns from deep-linked iOS Settings app?

Tags: ios, swift

I use deep-linking to let my users navigate to my app's page in the iOS **Settings** app, where I allow the user to set how many Core Data backups they want to store.

**Settings** is kind enough to provide a link back to the app, *which is awesome*, but I'd like to know when the user comes back specifically from **Settings** so that I can then prune the Core Data backups.

Is there a notification I can observe, or some other way I can tell when the app comes to the foreground specifically after leaving **Settings**?

I'm programming in Swift 4.2. Thanks!

Comment: What do you need to do or check for after returning from Settings? Also remember that your app will be killed and restarted if the user changes any privacy related setting for your app in the Settings app.

Comment: Thanks. One of my settings controls the number of core data backups my app maintains for my users. I want to check if I need to prune some of those backups, but only when coming back from Settings.

Comment: You should put that in your question.

Comment: Great. Will do.

Comment: Not tested, but there should be a `UserDefaults.didChangeNotification` notification you can subscribe to.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah that might be the way to handle it. My mind got stuck on looking for something specific to the Settings Bundle, but the change in User Defaults would work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @mschmidt, the answer was simple; I just needed to register an observer for UserDefaults.didChangeNotification. Something like the following:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(userDefaultsDidChange),
    name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification,
    object: nil
)

@objc private func userDefaultsDidChange() {
   coreData.pruneBackups()
}
```